# ¿Es buena idea establecer una función de gestión de errores definida por el usuario?

Tags: php, excepciones

Cómo saben PHP no tiene una buena gestión de errores, para poder capturar los errores que se generan en PHP, ya sean warnings o errores fatales, lo que hice fue convertir todos esos errores en Excepciones a través del uso de la función `set_error_handler()`, el código que tengo es:

```
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, array $errcontext) {
  if (0 === error_reporting()) {
    return false;
  }
  throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
});
```

de manera que si surge algún error lo puedo capturar a través del uso un bloque `try{} catch(){}`.

Sin embargo me queda la duda de que si esto es una buena manera de gestionar los errores que surjan en el script.

En base a su experiencia, **¿Se debería hacer esto, o existe alguna mejor manera de manejar los errores en `PHP`?**.

Answer (score 1):

Yo suelo capturar las excepciones de esta forma, escribiendo en un log las trazas y además elevándolas

```
try{
    if ($data['state'] == ""){  
        writeLog('Estado recibido vacio','error');
        throw new Exception('No se ha especificado el estado', '1002');
    }
}catch(Exception $ex){
    $error_code = $ex->getCode();
    $error_description = $ex->getMessage();
    $traza = ponerBarras($ex->getTraceAsString();
}


function writeLog($cadena,$tipo)
{
    $nivelLog = array(0=>"debug", 1=>"info", 2=>"error");
    $nivelLogEstablecido = "error";
    if (array_search($tipo, $nivelLog) >= array_search($nivelLogEstablecido, $nivelLog)){
        $arch = fopen(realpath( '.' )."/rutalogs/log_".date("Ymd").".txt", "a+"); 
        $t = microtime(true);
        $micro = sprintf("%06d",($t - floor($t)) * 1000000);
        $d = new DateTime( date('Y-m-d H:i:s.'.$micro, $t) );
        fwrite($arch, "[".$d->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u")." ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']." - $tipo ] ".$cadena."\n");
        fclose($arch);
    }
}
```